# Scrollable view with LinearLayout and ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I need to display listview and rest of the views after the listview in my Fragment.

First i tried using `ScrollView` instead of `LinearLayout` but when im using it ListView only show single row only.

Problem with LinearLayout is it does not scroll entire view. it only scroll through ListView Only. so other views are always hidden from the main view.

i want to make entire view scrollable with expanded listview. so there wont be two scrolling views. how can i do that?

My Fragment Layout is like below.

```
<FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView>
            /** List View **/
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout>
            /** Layouts that need to be display after list view **/
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You want linear layout view at the end of list view or on the same screen?

Comment: Samescreen after listview.

Comment: Let me clear my question,you want 70% of screen show list view and 30% show your layout? or after the completion on scroll of list view the last item of list view will be this view?

Comment: create `ScrollView > RelativeLayout > ListView and LinearLayout`, and set `below LinearLayout` property accoding to your need.

Comment: @RishabhMahatha ill explain again. its simple. i have Listview first then bottom of the list view there will be rest of the views i want to show to the user.  hope you got the idea.

Comment: see my answer, use that listview inside scrollview

Comment: I have added one answer, try this.

Comment: @Cade, use my code. It will give you proper result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this list view  with scroll view

```
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Context;

public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
{

boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

and in class

```
ExpandableHeightListView listView = new ExpandableHeightListView(this);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setExpanded(true);
```

in xml

```
<yourpackagename.ExpandableHeightListView 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          />
```

the list view will be expanded fully

Comment: Thanks. it worked. i dont know why we need to do that hack to make ListView expandable. there should be XML way of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

try this.

Comment: change parent `LinearLayout` width to `match_parent`.

Comment: nope. its not scrolling at all. half of my listview display and rest of the view are in bottom and i cannot scroll to view them.

Comment: without scroll view it working fine. but listview is not fully expanded. i want to show expanded listview first then rest of the views.

Comment: wait for a min..actually i am not getting you can you please send your code

Answer (score 1):

In Xml:

```
<!--Required to scroll the list view with Linear Layout-->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <!--Direct child container of scroll view-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.example.custom.ScrollableListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:divider="@color/colorDivider"
                    android:dividerHeight="0.09dp"
                    android:fadingEdge="none"
                    android:listSelector="@color/colorSelectedGreen"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--Direct child container of scroll view-->

        </ScrollView>
        <!--Required to scroll the list view with Linear Layout-->
```

Create a ScrollableListView custom class in java:

```
public class ScrollableListView extends ListView {

    public ScrollableListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 4, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try with Recycler Views as google now recommends using recycler views. You can put the recycler view inside a nested scroll view something like this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/loader2" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="26sp"
         />

    <app.so.city.appconstants.CustomTextViews.SourceRegularTextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
        android:textColor="#CC000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/article_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can put any number of views inside the nested scroll view.

**For the Scrolling to work perfectly and smoothly, you will also need to add the following line of code to java code for recycler views:**

```
recycler_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Give it a try and let me know if this works for you as well.